# Intent not passing data

Tags: java, android

I have an intent that passes an `integer` taken from the current day of the month. But when I print it to an excel sheet its blank.

Here is my first class that gets the day of the month and puts it into int day.

```
int day = datepicker.getDayOfMonth();

Intent intent = new Intent (OneWeekPlan.this, Save_File.class);
intent.putExtra("day", day);
intent.putExtra("wk1month", month);
intent.putExtra("wk1year", year);
intent.putExtra("wk1dayofweek", wk1dayofweek);
startActivity(intent);
```

Here is the class to take that input

```
    private boolean saveExcelFile(Context context, String fileName) { 

    // check if available and not read only 
    if (!isExternalStorageAvailable() || isExternalStorageReadOnly()) { 
        Log.e(TAG, "Storage not available or read only"); 
        return false; 
    } 

    boolean success = false; 


    String day = getIntent().getStringExtra("day");

    //New Workbook
    Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();

    Cell c1 = null;
    Cell c2 = null;
    Cell c3 = null;
    Cell c4 = null;
    Cell c5 = null;
    Cell c6 = null;
    Cell c7 = null;
    Cell c8 = null;
    Cell c9 = null;


    //Cell style for header row
    CellStyle cs = wb.createCellStyle();


    //New Sheet
    Sheet sheet1 = null;
    sheet1 = wb.createSheet("My PT Plan");

    // Generate column headings
    Row row1 = sheet1.createRow(0);

    //Create First Row that holds dates
    c1 = row1.createCell(0);
    c1.setCellValue("");
    c1.setCellStyle(cs);

    c1 = row1.createCell(1);
    c1.setCellValue(day);
    c1.setCellStyle(cs);

    c1 = row1.createCell(2);
    c1.setCellValue(day);
    c1.setCellStyle(cs);

    c1 = row1.createCell(3);
    c1.setCellValue(day);
    c1.setCellStyle(cs);

    c1 = row1.createCell(4);
    c1.setCellValue(day);
    c1.setCellStyle(cs);

    c1 = row1.createCell(5);
    c1.setCellValue(day);
    c1.setCellStyle(cs);


    //Set width of columns for first row
    sheet1.setColumnWidth(0, (15 * 300));
    sheet1.setColumnWidth(1, (15 * 300));
    sheet1.setColumnWidth(2, (15 * 300));
    sheet1.setColumnWidth(3, (15 * 300));
    sheet1.setColumnWidth(4, (15 * 300));
    sheet1.setColumnWidth(5, (15 * 300));

    // Create a path where we will place our List of objects on external storage         
    File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), fileName); 
    FileOutputStream os = null; 

    try { 
        os = new FileOutputStream(file);
        wb.write(os);
        Log.w("FileUtils", "Writing file" + file); 
        success = true; 
    } catch (IOException e) { 
        Log.w("FileUtils", "Error writing " + file, e); 
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        Log.w("FileUtils", "Failed to save file", e); 
    } finally { 
        try { 
            if (null != os) 
                os.close(); 
        } catch (Exception ex) { 
        } 
    } 
    return success; 
}
```

I'm sure there is no value in int day but I'm trying to figure out why. thanks.

Comment: Try to get int value using : getIntent().getIntExtra("day",0).

Comment: Print values before your send to value through intent,after that identify yourself.

Comment: @HareshChhelana, you are right there is a lot of confusion between primitive data type

Comment: ugh..of course imma dummy. thanks =)

Comment: when I do this my variable comes out as 0. I want it to pass the value from the original class. When I put it the var name such as int day = getIntent().getIntExtra("day", day); i get an error

Comment: @dtrodriguez You already got your answer . For better approach please use sharedpref. instead of putExtra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in first activity

```
    int day = datepicker.getDayOfMonth();
    Intent intent = new Intent (OneWeekPlan.this, Save_File.class);
    intent.putExtra("day", day);
    intent.putExtra("wk1month", month);
    intent.putExtra("wk1year", year);
    intent.putExtra("wk1dayofweek", wk1dayofweek);
    startActivity(intent);
```

in Secand Activity

```
int day = getIntent().getExtra().getInt("day");
int month= getIntent().getExtra().getInt("wk1month");
int year= getIntent().getExtra().getInt("wk1year");
int wk1dayofweek= getIntent().getExtra().getInt("wk1dayofweek");
```

Comment: this worked however i had to put int day = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("day") getExtra had to be plural. Eclipse caught it for me. But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

day is int value get int value using getIntExtra instead getStringExtra :

```
int day = getIntent().getIntExtra("day",0);
```

Comment: when I do this it prints out 0 for the variable. I want it to pass the value of the var to the other class int day = getIntent().getIntExtra("day", day); but I get an error  with this

Answer (score 0):

Look for below checks :

1. > Try Intent.hasExtra(String name)

   to check if an extra is passed in intent.
2. Try `Loging` value before you pass it to : `intent.putExtra("day", day)`

Answer (score 0):

You have already asked a similar question:

[How to use variables in other classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27064410/how-to-use-variables-in-other-classes/27065065#27065065)

I have already given an answer there. Instead of using `Intent` to pass data, you can use `SharedPreferences`. That will work in every class.